# Please explain the meaning of below sentece

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

```
 His death has deprived our country of true seer.
```

Here I did't understand what is *"of true seer"*.

Comment: Why don't you look up the word in a dictionary, eg in Oald -http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/seer

Comment: This sentence should really be "...of *a* true seer", because you have to use an article or other determiner when referring to a single object ("a seer") like this.

Answer (score 1):

A 'seer' is similar to a prophet or visionary. Probably it comes from the collision of the word "see" with the suffix "er", i.e. someone who sees.

So the country has lost someone who has a positive vision for the country and could presumably guide it towards a better future.